# Postgres Unique Sequences in one table based on owner/foreign key

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a web application that will store all user information in one database using permissions, roles, and FKs to restrict data access. One of the tables in this application tracks work orders created by each user (i.e. the work order table has an FK to the user table).

I am wanting to ensure that each user has their own uninterrupted sequence of 'work order IDs' that are assigned when the work order is scheduled. That is, if user 1 creates his first work order, it will assign it #1, however, if user 2 creates his fifth work order, it will assign it #5.

The work order table has a UUID primary key, so each record is distinguishable, and the user FK has a not-null constraint.

Based on my research so far, it seems like Postgres Sequences would likely be my best answer. I would need to create a sequence for each user, and incorporate it into a trigger to stamp the work order record with the next appropriate ID. However, this seems like it would be very performance intensive, and creating a new sequence for every user would have its own set of challenges.

A second approach could be to create a second table that tracks each user's latest sequence, query it, increment it, and update both the work order table and the number tracking table. However, in this scenario, I think it would be susceptible to race conditions if two users were to convert records at exactly the same time.

I'm unsure what the best way to solve the problem would be. Is there another way that would provide better performance?

Answer (score 0):

Sequences won't work for you, because they are not transactional by design: if an insert with a generated number fails, that number is consumed even after a `ROLLBACK`.

You should create a second table

```
CREATE TABLE counters (
   user_id bigint PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
   work_order_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Then you get the next number with

```
UPDATE counters
SET work_order_id = work_order_id + 1
RETURNING work_order_id;
```

That is atomic and safe from race conditions. Just make sure you run that update and the insert in the same database transaction, then they will either both succeed or both fail and be undone.

This will serialize inserts into the work orders table per user, but gap-less sequences are *always* a performance problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Would this be better to implement on the client-side and make 2 calls (first being the ID retrieval, second saving the record with the new ID) or implement it server-side somehow to ensure there are no failed calls?

Comment: I have added a sentence to the answer. You have to run the update and the insert in the same transaction, then both are rolled back if there is a problem.

Comment: As @Laurenz points out keeping a gap-less sequence is always a performance problem it also tends to become a maintenance nightmare. A better solution is to abandon it and just create 1 sequence for use by all users.  Typically, keeping a gap-less sequence is just not worth the effort required. Ask yourself what is the **business importance** of doing so?  If is necessary in your app to orders in sequence by user this is available by either timestamp or/and retaliative sequence. Just IMHO.

Comment: @Belayer, I've challenged the gapless sequence concept as well, but since these will be posted accounting documents, there cannot be any gaps in the numbering. If there were gaps, they could face issues should they ever come under audit.